# Crop display size in linux

Tags: linux, xorg, resolution, xorg.conf, xrandr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Limit video output to a section of a display and leave the rest blank](https://superuser.com/questions/248840/limit-video-output-to-a-section-of-a-display-and-leave-the-rest-blank)

My laptop has a slightly damaged lcd - it has a black strip on the right that reduces the working resolution from 1400x1050 to about 1375x1050 - thus hiding part of the right edge of the desktop, windows, or the mouse pointer should it be unwise enough to stray there.

Is there a way in linux to crop the monitor output so as to keep the screen inside the working area of the monitor?

edit: this is the same question as [Limit video output to a section of a display and leave the rest blank](https://superuser.com/questions/248840/limit-video-output-to-a-section-of-a-display-and-leave-the-rest-blank)

Answer (score 1):

While it has a bit of overhead and gives reduced graphics performance, you could use [`Xnest`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xnest) to run another X server (with any resolution you want) in a window in your inital X server.

Then you can place this window in the desired part of the screen, or (since it's the right hand side that's broken) just run bare Xorg without a window manager to have it placed in the top right with no window decorations.

Comment: Is there really no better way? I am considering using something like xfce and adding taskbar/pannels to each edge of my screen that are just empty and forbid windows for using that space; but Ideally I'd like the mouse restricted to the working portion as well.