# Macbook: reduce usable screen area

Tags: display, resolution, macbook

I broke my screen on 15 inch Macbook Retina and temporarily need to reduce the usable area of screen not to use 2 inches in the bottom and 1 inch on the left side. Wonder if this is possible :)

( This is not a duplicate of the other question as I have OS X obviously, not Windows. Thanks )

[image: Photo of broken screen]

Comment: There have been several similar questions; the ones I found in a quick search involved Linux machines.  The solutions pointed to using xrandr.  Not sure whether this will work on a Mac, but check out the answers here: http://superuser.com/questions/248840/limit-video-output-to-a-section-of-a-display-and-leave-the-rest-blank

Comment: If your screen is doing that, it will probably need replacing. It's a hardware issue.

Comment: Did you explore whether xrandr runs on OSX?  No luck there?

Comment: couldn't install it on first try, will try once again a bit later

Comment: Try changing the screen resolution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OS X you can change the underscan/overscan in the preferences. It wont be perfect as the setting can only change the size of the display not the position but it may help in the usability of the computer. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202763

You may also be able to use an external program such as DisplayConfigX if it is supported by your operating system. http://www.3dexpress.de/#Overscan

Hope this helps until you can get a more permanent solution.

Comment: Thanks! Too bad 'underscan' works only while 'mirroring to a TV or projector'. Don't see that option when nothing external connected. Getting a replacement screen next week, so no comment on the second option.